# Node.js global variable accessibility

Tags: javascript, node.js, global-variables

I am trying to write a NodeJS based application for which I declare a global variable and try to modify it in one of the functions in my code. But it does not get modified. The code looks something like this:

```
var num=0, check = true;
function( a, b){
  var parts = a.split("/");
  while (num == 0){
    check=false;
    fileSystem.readFile(parts[parts.length-1], function (err, fileData) {  .
    .
    check= true
    }
 }
 if(check == true){
   num++;
   console.log("check: "+check+"num"+num);
 }
}
```

I see value of num as 0 always. I also tried to use global.num inside the function but it dint work. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't `.readFile()` asynchronous? Its callback (where you set `num=1`) won't be called until sometime later, so I would expect you've got an infinite loop with `while(num==0)`.

Comment: The value of variable doesn't change even after the callback is invoked which I check by console.log() in callback.

Comment: Line 6: SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

Comment: that might be because of dots I put to skip non relevant part of code.

Answer (score 0):

Your function hasn't been invoked yet, so there's no reason for the value of num to have changed.

Comment: Updated the code to reflect the problem I am facing.I hope you understand the issue. Can you please suggest how can I solve this problem?

Comment: my answer is the same. I don't see where your function is being invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Even if your function were to be invoked, it contains an infinite loop (as far as I can tell, since you seem to have omitted some code in the loop). It will loop forever because it tests if `num` is 0, but `num` is only changed *after* the loop exits.

Comment: The loop is not running infinite. The code within doesn't let it run forever. But even after the process is invoked and run finitely the global variable value does not change.

Comment: Perhaps you need to show all your code. The code that is currently shown *does* let the loop run forever.

Comment: Remember Node is asynchronous but runs in a single thread.  Your 'while' loop is saturating the thread so the callback never gets a chance to execute and therefore its caught in an infinite loop.

Comment: Even if the callback gets hit there is no way out of the while loop as it is presented.